# Add toggle button on ribbon bar through configuration

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, cme, configuration

Is there possibility to set the button type, so it can have the same look as "Context Menu" button.
[image]

Current component configuration looks the following way:

```
            <ext:ribbontoolbars>
                <ext:add>
                    <ext:extension assignid="RB_Test" name="Test" pageid="HomePage" groupid="ShowGroup">
                        <ext:command>TestCM</ext:command>
                        <ext:title>Test</ext:title>
                        <ext:issmallbutton>false</ext:issmallbutton>
                        <ext:dependencies>
                            <cfg:dependency>Test.Commands</cfg:dependency>
                        </ext:dependencies>
                        <ext:apply>
                            <ext:view name="EditorView" />
                        </ext:apply>
                    </ext:extension>
                </ext:add>
            </ext:ribbontoolbars>
```